# check whether a textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is with this code:

```
function c(id)
{
    var empty = document.getElementById(id);
    if(empty.length<1)
    {
        window.alert ("This field cant be left empty");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is my html code:

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="80" id="ta1" onChange="c('ta1');"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value property of the textarea should be checked to determine if it is empty.

```
   var content = document.getElementById(id).value;

   if(content.length<1)
   {
        window.alert ("This field cant be left empty");
        return true;
   }
   else
   {
        return false;
   }
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/35DFR/2/

Comment: what is the issue?  Have you checked the example?

Comment: yes I did.when i fill in the text area, i'm getting the aleart window which is supposed to come when the text area is empty

Comment: I updated the example which should meet your requirements.  Please not the example is more of a demonstration of using the value property.  Is there an issue with the posted solution?  Did you notice that alert was spelled wrong in the posted code?

Comment: No sir, no alert box is araising now for any of the cases

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function c(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).value == '')
    {
        window.alert ("This field cant be left empty");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

If you want to go a bit further, you might want to trim the value first though.

Update:

From the comments, try changing the '**onchange**' to '**onkeyup**':

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="80" id="ta1" onkeyup="c('ta1');"></textarea>
```

Comment: try changing your 'onchange' to 'onkeyup'

Answer (score 0):

```
if (YOURFORM.YOURTEXTFIELDVARIABLENAME.value == "")

{
     return True

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function c(id) {
    var empty =document.getElementById(id);
    if(!empty.value){
        window.alert("This field cant be left empty");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

try this